# Vigenère cipher frequency analysis not working

Tags: vigenere, frequency-analysis

I'm writing a C++ program to use the [Kasiski method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasiski_examination) to crack the Vigenère cipher. I'm testing it with a bit of Shakespeare encrypted with the key `ABCDEFGHIJKL`. It can find the key length, (even when I changed it), but when I started using frequency analysis, the poem's frequency doesn't seem to fit with normal english; in some lines, `T` occurs twice as much as `E` when `I` try to do frequency analysis.

```
cout << "The key length is most likely " << len << "." << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
    string m;
    int j = 0;
    do {
        m += ciphertext[i + len * j];
    } while (i + len * j++ < length(ciphertext));
    cout << m << endl;
}
```

So I input

```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```

and it finds the length 12 and it gets the 1st, 13th, 25th, etc. characters, and it correctly gives

```
UFFSUGBVUBTTOJPFUBODJDEXPQEFOEBFGPUUQTPXUDIXEMEUUPIQPZIILPETBSVBHIFNPUULFXZUUDXBUPL
UGO
```

But when I analyze the string separately, there are almost twice as more `U`s (correspond to `T`) than `F`s (correspond to `E`). I think I did something wrong here…

Comment: Maybe just run the frequency analysis on the actual text? It is possible, that this part of text does not fit the standard language distribution (don't forget, it takes every 12th symbol). And did you encounter similar problems with the other ensembles of characters (chars at 2,14,26,... ; 3,15,27,...;...)?

Comment: @tylo It's not only that part of text. Out of the 11 sequences generated from the square, 4-5 of them don't have the right frequencies...

Comment: Here goes testing with key length 15...

Comment: @tylo Key `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO` still causes the same problems; frequency analysis thinks it goes ~something like `PBODP...`

Comment: ah, you are not sure about the keylength yet. That explains quite a bit. Good luck on trying.

Comment: @tylo actually I am. It deduces the key length correctly.

Comment: After a quick glance with an online tool: You're right, and the frequency discrepancy comes from the plain text. Literature can be tricky for frequency analysis, since they utilize the language in uncommon ways.

Comment: @tylo OK, So it's not that I'm making an error but that I'm using some coincindentally unanalyzable plaintext?

Comment: For this amount of text that's entirely possible. The larger the text, the better the statistics (unless it is off on purpose, e.g. poems could do that).

Comment: Since no one is talking like Shakespeare today, there are differences in language characteristics. For example, in his works the word *thou* (and its different cases, e.g. *thee, thy*) is used quite a lot, but in any modern english this would be *you* instead => leads to an increase in *t* and a decrease in *y*

Comment: The problem is due to the small ciphertext you've used. When using something like 12 letter length key, what you have for frequency analysis would be 12th the amount of the whole ciphertext. Thus too small for analysis. Use a sample with 12k letters and then assess the results.